# Do repeated chat suspensions have any permanent effect on your account?

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

Currently the way chat suspensions work is if you are found to have posted an offensive or offensive or otherwise unacceptable post, you might get flagged and subsequently suspended from chat. Usually this is a warning that what a user is posting is unacceptable, but sometimes users simply wait for the suspension time to pass and continue posting offensive material.

Is there a system in place to ban a repeated offender from the chat in question if (s)he gets over a certain number of chat suspensions? If there isn't, should there be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no further automatic system, but moderators can suspend users from chat manually. There is no general rule tied to the number of flags, but if you attract a high number of flags you might want to ask yourself what you are doing wrong to attract that kind of attention.

If a user is continuing to post offensive content, raise a moderator flag (different from the spam/offensive flag) in chat and mention that the user has a history of posting offensive content. Moderators have access to the user's history and can take more drastic measures than the automated suspension. But they need to be made aware of the problem to be able to act.

Comment: If someone repeatedly posts offensive stuff, definitely raise a flag as Mad Scientist. I've seen a user get flagged *dozens* of times before a manual suspension was put into place. If mods don't know, they can't do anything.

Comment: `>>definitely raise a flag as Mad Scientist.` From my secret volcano lair, on a stormy night, just as thunder claps dramatically behind me, I will cackle with maniacal laughter and click flag for moderator.

Comment: @Hans That's certainly a better idea than what I meant to say, so I recommend doing that instead